# break from asynchronous task android

Tags: android

I would like to stop my asynchronous thread on back click of user.
Could you please suggest if there is any way to stop asynchronous thread in android.
Please forward your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about `AsyncTask` then you can call its `cancel()` method. If you pass `true` to this method and the task is waiting on some object or I/O operation then the waiting will be interrupted and the task will be cancelled. But if you pass `false` to this method or the task is not waiting (e.g. performing some calculations) then it will not be cancelled. In this case you can call `isCancelled()` method from `doInBackground()` and finish calculations when `isCancelled()` returns `true`.